# How to access JNDI data source defined in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I have created a JNDI data-source using my weblogic console but I am not able to access the object from my web application. Below are the details

In weblogic 10.3.6, I have given the JNDI name for datasource  as : `jdbc/mydb`

To get DB connection from my web application I have written this code in my web application:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
jndiConnection = ds.getConnection();
```

Earlier I was using Tomcat as server and I was able to get DB connection when I configured the resource details in the file `tomcat/conf/server.xml`, but when I am using started using weblogic server I am getting below error:

```
Cannot establish DB connection to JNDI:java:/comp/env/jdbc/mydb While trying to look up /comp/env/jdbc/mydb in /app/webapp/sample.war/1811641702. caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jdbc/mydb in /app/webapp/sample.war/1811641702.; remaining name '/comp/env/jdbc/mydb'
```

I have tried the options mentioned in this link : [How to lookup JNDI resources on WebLogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500632/how-to-lookup-jndi-resources-on-weblogic) but still I am facing problems.

Please let me know where I am doing mistake, what is the process of accessing the JNDI object.

Comment: Did you mean to name it "jdbc/mydb" instead of "java/mydb"?

Comment: Also have you tried the second solution in the link in your question? The first answer applies to Tomcat but I'm not sure that always works in weblogic. Remove java:comp/env/ and try initContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb")?

Comment: yes, even that is not working, I am getting below error in that case: Cannot establish DB connection to JNDI:jdbc/mydb While trying to lookup 'jdbc.mydb' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved '' caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.mydb' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/mydb'

Comment: The answer works on Weblogic 12.1.3 as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After referring to the post:[Tomcat vs Weblogic JNDI Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676/tomcat-vs-weblogic-jndi-lookup?rq=1) I have modified my code.

Using below code in my java program of web application has solved my issue:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
jndiConnection = ds.getConnection();
```

Also in weblogic console I have added my JNDI object to my Admin Server (under servers option) where my web application is deployed.

Comment: So you did exactly what I told you to do in my comment and it worked... derp. Come on man!

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp: Think you should have summed up your comments in an answer.

Comment: I had the same problem that the JNDI resource was not found, although I created it before. The key is to assign the resource to a specific server.

Answer (score 3):

Tried your answer in weblogic 12c but not worked..!

When i tried by using only the name of dataSource `myDB` (removed the `jdbc/`) it worked fine.

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("myDB");
jndiConnection = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: The JNDI name that I have created itself has value as "jdbc/mydb", so I cannot remove that.

Answer (score 2):

The same solution for Weblogic 12c would be

add the below dependency to your pom.xml.. create a variable with current middleware home value ${oracleMiddlewareHome}, then...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>
            ${oracleMiddlewareHome}/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar
        </systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Now use the below code :

```
 Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>(7);
h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");//add ur url
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");//add username
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "welcome1");//add password

    Bundle bundle;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(h);
       DataSource dataSource = ((DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/ContextBindingDS"));
        bundle = (Bundle) ctx.lookup(BUNDLE_JNDI_NAME);


    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```