# Connect to WebLogic's JNDI datasource from Java Web Application

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I have followed one of the answer here :

[How to access JNDI data source defined in weblogic 10.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218663/how-to-access-jndi-data-source-defined-in-weblogic-10-3-6?rq=1)

```
Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>(7);
        h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");//add ur url
        h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");//add username
        h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "abc#12345");//add password

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(h);
        DataSource dataSource = ((DataSource) ctx.lookup("jndiDS"));
```

when running it i got this error :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder.(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;[Ljava/lang/String;)V

and try running it again it gives different error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper

what could be the problem here? i have added wlclient.jar to maven dependency

Comment: If your web application and the datasource are hosted by the same server (JVM) you just need this to get your datasource :  
`InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();  
DataSource dataSource = ((DataSource) ctx.lookup("jndiDS"));`

Comment: what if my application is hosted on tomcat?

Comment: and the datasource under weblogic ? Bad idea. Create your datasource in tomcat.

Comment: welp, okay then. i was thinking for easier debugging, since i'm using tomcat plugin on maven.