# Trouble using @Resource and JNDI lookup

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

I'm having trouble applying the concept of injection and also JNDI with EJBs and I'd like your help. I am learning this and I really want to understand and apply the techniques of @Resource and/or JNDI lookups with XML configuration. I can't seem to find any of the initial parameters in my JNDI lookups. Now, before I continue, if I manually enter the JNDI name of my datasource, everything works great. What I'm trying to do (again as an exercise) is use @Resource or JNDI to get the JNDI datasource name itself and then do a JNDI lookup on the datasource. I know that you can directly inject a DataSource object but if I can't inject a String, I gotta start with this.

First, here's the important part of my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<env-entry>
    <description>DataSource JNDI lookup name</description>
    <env-entry-name>datasourceName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>myDataSource</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

In terms of injection using @Resource I've tried I've tried the following field in the EJB

```
@Resource(name = "datasourceName")
String dsName;
```

I've also tried with mappedName and lookup (using JNDI lookup) nothing is coming in. Then I've tried JNDI lookup as follows:

```
 // get JNDI name from environment entry in EJB Context and use to lookup DataSource
Context context = new InitialContext();
String dsName = (String) context.lookup("java:comp/env/SRS/datasourceName");
```

(The name of the application is SRS) - This comes up with a NamingException that the JNDI lookup did not find anything. I've tried the following lookups:

```
String datasourceName = (String) context.lookup("java:comp/env/SRS/Status/datasourceName"); // name of EJB is Status
String datasourceName = (String) context.lookup("datasourceName");
String datasourceName = (String) context.lookup("SRS/datasourceName");           
String datasourceName = (String) context.lookup("SRS/Status/datasourceName");           
String datasourceName = (String) context.lookup("java:global/SRS/datasourceName");
String datasourceName = (String) context.lookup("java:global/SRS/Status/datasourceName");
```

My first post here so I hope I asked properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500632/how-to-lookup-jndi-resources-on-weblogic If it really is just `datasourceName` it seems like `context.lookup("datasourceName");` should be working. The other thing you can check is in the admin console, go to `Summary of Servers->your server name->View JNDI tree` and make sure your datasourceName is showing up.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp - Thanks for responding. The datasource works out fine. Meaning, if I attempt a JNDI lookup for the datasource directly with the following code `DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("myDataSource");` I can access the datasource. What I'm trying to do here is use the XML configuration to supply a String directly to the EJB. I hope that clarified.

Comment: If `@Resource(name="datasourceName")` is used, then `java:comp/env/datasourceName` is the correct lookup string.  That said, I don't know why the injection isn't working when the same name is specified in the annotation and XML; that should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Two days later I saw that my mistake was nowhere in the code of the EJB itself but in a configuration of the JSP which invoked the EJB!! My mistake is that I had somehow invoked the methods of the EJB class as a POJO and NOT through the container. I had assumed since the EJB methods were being called that the container had correctly injected the EJB to the JSP. But it didn't. I put in a JNDI lookup in the JSP and everything resolved itself. Thanks everyone for your responses!