# Weblogic 10.3.5 EJB3 local seesion bean lookup from java main class

Tags: ejb, weblogic, local

I am using **Weblogic 10.3.5** and EJB 3 for session bean

but I am not able to lookup jndi for local stateless session bean even though I am able to lookup

remote bean successfully

my code are for main class is

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");

    try {

        Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);

        TheBeanRemote bean = (TheBeanRemote) ctx
                .lookup("MrBean#com.bdc.TheBeanRemote");
        System.out.println(bean.sayHello());

        TheLocalLocal bean2 = (TheLocalLocal) ctx.lookup("TheLocalLocal");
        Object obj = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/MrBean2");

        System.out.println(bean2.sayHello());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Remote Bean**

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface TheBeanRemote {

```
public String sayHello();
```

}

**Local Bean**

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local(TheLocalLocal.class)
public interface TheLocalLocal {

```
public String sayHello();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're running as a "client", that is a remote call, if that app is running on the server itself, that is a local call. It makes sense that one works but not the other.

The properties you're using indicate a **remote call**:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);
```

A **local call** is:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
```

See a similar question here: [How to lookup JNDI resources on WebLogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500632/how-to-lookup-jndi-resources-on-weblogic)

Comment: Thanks for reply,
When I am using context object without passing Properties object and try to access as you have suggested above for local bean then I am getting following


javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Please let me know where is problem because from many day I am facing same problem

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post the full exception? - you can edit your original question to add more info. Sounds like it might be a classpath issue

Comment: full exception::


javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
 at com.bdc.Main.main(Main.java:33)