# Java servlet context causes too many MySQL connections

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a site built with Java EE. When the site starts I wrote a context listener in `index.jsp` to open MySQL connection for future use :

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)  { 
    try {
        ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        DatabaseController db_controller = new DatabaseController();
        db_controller.connectoDatabase();
        servletContext.setAttribute("db_controller", db_controller);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And get the attribute `db_controller` in my jsp page :

```
<%
    DatabaseController db_controller = (DatabaseController)application.getAttribute("db_controller");
    out.print("<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;You have " +db_controller.getClientNumber()+ 
    " clients and "+db_controller.getJobNumber()+" jobs. </span>");
%>
```

The problem is that when I refresh the site ten times, MySQL shows error said "Too many connections". I entered MySQL and saw thousands of connections in "sleep" state.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? I do not want to increase connection number because it's not good idea. I did write a context destroyer but it doesn't work :

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)  { 
    ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    DatabaseController db_controller = (DatabaseController) servletContext.getAttribute("db_controller");
    db_controller.closeConnection();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're not using a container-managed connection pool?

Comment: @Powerlord I am new to Java EE and I code the site without using framework, where can I get a container-managed connection pool?

Comment: Generally, a container-managed connection pool is set up on the JavaEE server and then retrieved using a [JNDI lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500632/how-to-lookup-jndi-resources-on-weblogic) on the name you setup in the JavaEE server..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc

Comment: @Powerlord I'll have a look, but can't I do this manually in an easier way? I want one single connection to database for my site and that's all I want at the moment.