# how to access the JNDI tree of the adminserver in a weblogic cluster?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

I have a cluster with an admin server, server 1 and server 2
the application is deployed to the cluster to server 1 and 2.

the following code works fine if I deploy the application in a local, single server

`InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
(MBeanServer) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/domainRuntime");`

but once deployed to cluster it fails ( NamingException)

looking at the JNDI tree, I see that jmx/domainRuntime is available only in the adminserver.

so basically that is the reason of my question, how that access that resource in the adminserver if the application is in server 1 or 2.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to specify `Context.PROVIDER_URL` as a property passed to `InitialContext` ?

Comment: since this code is server side ( it is a WAR application deployed to weblogic), I do not need to add the Provider. here the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jndi/jndi.html#wp467267

Comment: I have not used Weblogic for years so I can't help you with a solution. However I managed to locate the current docs for you at [Oracle® Fusion Middleware Developing Custom Management Utilities Using JMX for Oracle WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JMXCU/toc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WJNDI/wls_jndi.htm#i473354 you should take the following approach :

**Example 2-7 Using the Naming Service in a WebLogic Cluster**

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
       "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://acmeCluster:7001");
try {
  Context ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
  // Do the client's work
}
catch (NamingException ne) {
  // A failure occurred
}
finally {
  try {ctx.close();}
  catch (Exception e) {
    // a failure occurred
  }
}
```

You should also refer to : [How to lookup JNDI resources on WebLogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500632/how-to-lookup-jndi-resources-on-weblogic)

and the top answer contained therein i.e.

```
Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>(7);
h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, pURL); //For example "t3://127.0.0.1:7001"
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, pUsername);
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pPassword);

InitialContext context = new InitialContext(h).........
```

Comment: Updated the answer and the link even though the information contained therein is the same...

Answer (score -1):

Just change the block of code from your code and this will ask you to import package just do it, this will work:

```
Environment env = new Environment();
env.setProviderUrl("localhost");
env.setSecurityPrincipal("username");
env.setSecurityCredentials("password");``
if(ctx == null) {
    try {
        ctx = env.getInitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("SAML2IdentityAsserterProviderImpl: Exception " );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not wanswering the question, the question is about domain with multiple servers, thank you